# Can not convert PDF file to PCL after insert image into PDF file

Tags: zend-framework, ghostscript, printer-control-language

I have an original PDF file (one page) and one transparent background image. After I using Zend Pdf to insert image into PDF file, I would like to print this PDF file (including transparent background image). I using ghostscript (or convert) in UNIX to convert PDF to PCL but when I open PCL file using RedTitan EscapseE so I'm just see image without PDF original data. Please help me to solve this problem :(

this is ghostscript command which using to convert PDF to PCL

```
gs -sDEVICE=ljet4 -sOutputFile=test.pcl -q -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE TEST_34.PDF
```

TEST_34.PDF is PDF file include transparent background image

This is the link to download PDF file (TEST_34.PDF): "http://www.mediafire.com/view/u242l979jsb22gs/TEST_34.PDF"

Comment: In the file, the image is in FOREground. Looks like transparency not preserved/simulated in final format.

Comment: Using the current Ghostscript, and the command line listed, I get a PCL file which, when rendered with GhostPCL looks the same as the PDF file (though its grey instead of coloured). What version of Ghostscript are you using ?

Comment: I'm using ghostscript 5.50. what version of ghostscript are you using ? KenS